# Error Azure Synapse Notebook: ImportError: tokenizers>=0.10.1,<0.11 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found tokenizers==0.9.2

Tags: python, azure, huggingface-transformers, azure-synapse

I am trying to execute the below command in Azure synapse Notebook.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM 
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

However, I am getting the below error.

```
ImportError: tokenizers>=0.10.1,<0.11 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found tokenizers==0.9.2.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git master
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import dependency_versions_check

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/dependency_versions_check.py", line 41, in <module>
    require_version_core(deps[pkg])

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 120, in require_version_core
    return require_version(requirement, hint)

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 114, in require_version
    _compare_versions(op, got_ver, want_ver, requirement, pkg, hint)

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 50, in _compare_versions
    f"{requirement} is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found {pkg}=={got_ver}.{hint}"

ImportError: tokenizers>=0.10.1,<0.11 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found tokenizers==0.9.2.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git master
```

The above error is there even after I upgraded the transformer and tokenizer version, and validated it by below code:

```
import pkg_resources
for d in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print(d)
```

Sample output of the above code:

```
transformers 4.10.3
tokenizers 0.10.3
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
pip list | grep packaging
```

to check if the version of your packaging is upper than 21.3

try to reinstall your packaging , like this

```
pip install packaging==21.3
```

this issue have something to do with the format requirements in new packaging version checking

I think i should add a comment rather than add an answer here since this answer may not solve your problem, but I don't have enough reputation so sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command in you console:

```bash
pip install -I transformers --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `pip install packaging==21.3` worked.

it was just because of the package version discrepancy.

just make sure you have the correct version of the dependencies that you can check by `pipdeptree` if you do not have pipdeptree use `pip install pipdeptree`.